# Calculating volume of body enclosed by surfaces (double integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have to calculate the volume of body enclosed by following surfaces

$x^2+y^2=9$; (cylinder)

$x+y+z=10$;

$z=0$

[image]

My first task is construct body's projection on $0_{xy}$ plane, which is circle with R=3

Then, I have to construct inequality system to describe $D$
At this point, I can't figure out whether I am supposed to convert into polar coordinates, giving me 
$$
D=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0⩽r⩽3 \\ 
0⩽θ⩽π \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Or

Use Cartesian coordinates. I have browsed similar questions, and I have seen cylinder volume being solved both via Cartesian and polar coordinates.

In short, my question is whether 
$$\int_π^3dθ\int_0^3rsin(θ)\cdot rdr$$
integral for above equations correct?

EDIT
Okay, so I am doing the following

$$
D=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0⩽r⩽3 \\ 
0⩽θ⩽2π \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$V=\int_{A}z(x,y)\>dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 (10-r\cos\theta-r\sin\theta)rdr d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3(10r-r^2\cos\theta-r^2\sin\theta)dr d\theta=\int_0^2 (5r\cdot3^2-\frac{3^3}{3}-\frac{3^3}{3})df=45\theta-9sin\theta-9(-cos\theta)=90\pi+9$$

When integrating, I get $90+9π$. Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, the volume integral is

$$V=\int_{A}z(x,y)\>dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 (10-r\cos\theta-r\sin\theta)rdr d\theta=90\pi$$

Edit:

$$V=\int_0^3dr\int_0^{2\pi}(10r-r^2\cos\theta-r^2\sin\theta) d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^3 (20\pi r-r^2\sin\theta|_0^{2\pi}+r^2\cos\theta|_0^{2\pi})dr$$
$$=\int_0^3 (20\pi r+0+0)dr=20\pi\int_0^3rdr=90\pi$$

Comment: I figured out how conversion formula works in some other cases, however could you please clarify where $10$ comes from?

Comment: @Arnie - Note $z(x,y)=10 - x - y = 10-r\cos\theta-r\sin\theta$

Comment: Edited, when integrating I get $90\pi+9$

Comment: @Arnie - Edited the answer to include the integrating result.